Setting output width in IguanaTeX
I am using IguanaTeX to create equations in a powerpoint. I would like to make each equation a seperate numbered object so that I can animate each one. However, they also need to be the same width so they align nicely. Here is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathdots, cases}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage[layoutwidth=5in, hmargin=0in]{geometry}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
C\frac{d}{dt}T_B = \dot{Q}_p-\dot{Q}_{out}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

I have tried multiple variations of this, including the commented out line, but I can not get the equation to be 5" wide. Currently, it generates as 7.76", but if I change the equation, the width also changes. What am I doing wrong?
Output Log from updated code
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.8)  3 JUN 2024 11:31
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**IguanaTex_tmp.tex
(./IguanaTex_tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ar
ticle.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count193
\Gm@cntv=\count194
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count195
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2022-08-05 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box52
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count199
) (./IguanaTex_tmp.aux)
\openout1 = `IguanaTex_tmp.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(0.0pt, 361.34999pt, 0.0pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 794.96999pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=361.34999pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=361.34999pt
* \textheight=794.96999pt
* \oddsidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \evensidemargin=-72.26999pt
* \topmargin=-109.26999pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=0.0pt
* \marginparsep=0.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
[1

] (./IguanaTex_tmp.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1035 strings out of 477678
 18024 string characters out of 5833462
 325864 words of memory out of 5000000
 19901 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,62p,167b,102s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on IguanaTex_tmp.dvi (1 page, 556 bytes).


layoutwidth only affects the layout. It doesn't change the paper size.

You should report this to IguanaTeX's GitHub tracker, I think. I suspect it is related to the Mac issue, but I'm not sure if the developer is aware there's a problem on Windows, too. Note that I'm pretty sure some of the extra space is added by design. I don't think the plugin tries to set a tight bounding box like LaTeXIt.

layoutwidth only affects the layout. It doesn't alter the width of the paper. It's intended for e.g. laying out a smaller page on a larger piece of paper to allow for binding and trimming. If you want the PDF to be 5", you need to change the size of the paper.
I've added verbose so you get information on the terminal/in the log from geometry. Don't set \textwidth manually if using geometry as it just undermines the package's ability to calculate things correctly. Either stick to geometry or do it all by hand.
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0in,paperwidth=5in,verbose,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt]{geometry}
% \setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
C\frac{d}{dt}T_B = \dot{Q}_p-\dot{Q}_{out}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I tried this and it still doesn't work correctly. For the given equation it outputs as 7.76" wide and for a longer equation it is wider at 8.41".

@akb427 Did you compile exactly this code in a new document? If so, please update your question to include the log file from that compilation. When I compile the code above I get a PDF which is 127mm wide i.e. 5". So if you get a different result, I'd need to see the log.

Yes I did. I updated the question to include the output log.

@akb427 What compilation command did you use? I ask because the first line says the format is pdflatex but the backend used is dvips.  Whereas if I compile with pdflatex, I get the pdf backend; if I compile with latex, I get the latex format. I'm puzzled why you'd have the pdflatex format, but the l3 backend selected ends up as dvips.

In the IguanaTex editor, I selected "latex (DVI)" as the LaTeX Engine. Everything else was set up following the github page. I have tried changing that to "pdflatex" but that didn't effect it either.

@akb427 I've asked in chat about this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65747355#65747355. What confuses me is the mix. If I compile with latex (i.e. for DVI), I get the dvips backend, but I don't get the pdflatex format. I get latex, which makes sense. I can't understand how you end up with that mixture regardless of which engine is used. I just wondered if you were passing some odd option, but I really have no idea.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@akb427 See https://github.com/Jonathan-LeRoux/IguanaTex/issues/39. That concerns Macs, but it's not clear to me there's not an issue for Windows lurking here as well. I don't know enough about the application to really tell. (Posting this here rather than in chat for reference.)

I use paperwidth=32.6cm and it works fine.

@koppor you've lost me, sorry.

I used the answer. It compiles, but I still had breaks left of the width of the slide. Then, I changed paperwidth=5in in your answer to paperwidth=32.6cm. This made the LaTeX display grow to the width of my PowerPoint slide. -- I think, I did not fully read your answer, because the important information is "If you want the PDF to be 5", which is not the thing I needed. I needed a fully-grown LaTeX display. I was in a hurry, because some deadlines needed to be kept. Thus, I just copied your answer and it did not work (because the break was earlier).

@koppor that was because 5" was in the question ;). the point is, you need to set the paper width to whatever width you want the pdf to be. obviously, if you don't want 5", you have to substitute whatever you want instead. (or just take the code and modify it when it doesn't do what you want, is always an option. so your method is works, too.)
